# Как отправить сообщение в телеграмм канал в заданное время

Tags: java, telegram

Подскажите, как можно отправить сообщение в телеграмм канал в заданное время или по расписанию, чтобы один раз выполнился код и создал план отправки нескольких сообщений?

Answer (score 1):

Запускаете таймер и ждёте его окончания. После, отправляете всё что нужно в телеграмм.

**Как это сделать?**

В Java есть классы `Timer` и `TimerTask` из пакета `java.util`, которые позволяют планировать запуск задания на определённое время в будущем. Вы можете создать поток, выполняющий в фоновом режиме и ожидающий заданное время. Когда время истечёт, задача, связанная с этим потоком, будет запущена. С помощью параметров можно запланировать задачу на повторяющий запуск либо на запуск по определённой дате. Вам не нужно создавать поток с помощью класса `Thread`, так как таймер упрощает эту задачу.

Классы `Timer` и `TimerTask` работают в связке. Класс `Timer` используется для планирования выполнения задачи. Запланированная к выполнению задача должна быть экземпляром класса `TimerTask`. Вы сначала создаёте объект класса `TimerTask`, а затем планируете его запуск с помощью класса `Timer`.

Класс `TimerTask` реализует интерфейс `Runnable` и может быть использован для создания потока выполнения.

В классе `TimerTask` имеется абстрактный метод `run()`, который следует переопределить. Метод должен содержать исполняемый код.

Метод `cancel()` прерывает задание и возвращает значение true, если выполнение задания прервано.

Метод `scheduleExecutionTime()` возвращает время, на которое последний раз планировался запуск задания.

Как только задача создана, она планируется для выполнения объектом класса `Timer`.

Методы класса `Timer`:

- `void cancel()` - прерывает поток таймера
- `int purge()` - удаляет прерванные задания из очереди таймера
- `void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` - задание task планируется к выполнению через период в миллисекундах, переданный в параметре delay
- `void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` - задание `task` планируется к выполнению через период в миллисекундах, переданный в параметре `delay`. Затем задание повторяется повторно периодически - каждые `period` миллисекунд
- `void schedule(TimerTask task, Date when)` - задание `task` планируется на время, указанное в параметре when
- `void schedule(TimerTask task, Date when, long period)` - задание `task` планируется на время, указанное в параметре when. Затем задание выполняется повторно периодически - каждые `period` миллисекунд
- `void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` - задание `task` планируется к выполнению через период в миллисекундах, переданный в параметре `delay`. Затем задание выполняется повторно периодически - каждые `period` миллисекунд. Время каждого повтора задаётся относительно первого запуска.
- `void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date when, long period)` - задание `task` планируется к выполнению на время, указанное в параметре `when`. Задание затем выполняется повторно периодически - каждые `period` миллисекунд. Время каждого повтора задаётся относительно первого запуска.

Между методами `schedule()` и `scheduleAtFixedRate()` есть небольшая разница, которая заключается в разном поведении, которое зависит от стартовой точки запуска. Так второй метод работает как `startTime + iterationNumber * delayTime` и помнит время запуска. А обычный метод `schedule()` помнит последнее время выполнения и работает по формуле `lastExecutionTime + delayTime`. Для быстрых операций это не сильно отличается, а при ресурсоёмких задачах разница будет заметна, например, при работе сборщика мусора приложение может притормозить и следующая задача может запуститься чуть позже.

Как только объект класса `Timer` создан, запуск планируется вызовом его метода `schedule()` и его родственника (см. выше).
*П.С. Взято отсюда:* *[источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php)*

**Пример реализации таймера:**

```
private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

public void startTimer(){
    // 1000 - время в мс, через которое будет запущена задача
    mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 1000);
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Вот тут делаем всё что нужно (отправляем данные в телеграмм и т.п.)
    }
}
```

Comment: Да как-то это не рационально на мой взгляд, зачем делать так, чтобы все время выполнялась программа. в Приложении телеграмма, если долго нажать на кнопку отправления сообщения появится предложение отправить сообщение по расписанию, по идее должна быть возможность отправлять так сообщение программно?

Comment: @stvo не путайте приложение телеграм и бота.